# Is there a way to make time pass other than resting in your house

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm often around at night wishing day would come already. Is there any way to have your character wait until morning other than resting at your home?

Comment: Killing yourself makes some time pass, though I don't know the amount of time offhand, and you of course end up at a hospital. I assueme getting arrested does as well.

Comment: Some missions will advance time as well, but that doesn't really help in your circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

No, but there are ways of speeding up the time,
Dying,
Getting arrested,
Missions
Or just sleeping.

Comment: And Booty Calls

Comment: These options save money compared to the taxi ride.

Answer (score 5):

Getting long distance cab rides and skipping them then pressing right button to whistle them before they drive off. Repeat as required, the time that passes depends on the distance traveled.

Comment: What's the ratio (of distance and money spent to time passed)?